# Format drive by c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to format a drive in c++, but when I tried to use Format function of windows.h I could not find a sample or the way of using that.
I also don't want to interact by user in order to get ok or cancel so I cannot use SHFormat

Does anyone know how can I do that?

Comment: What "Format function of windows.h" would that be?

Comment: For some reason, formatting a harddrive without user acceptance gives me quite a chill.  Gonna be fun to test as well.

Comment: @Michael: Ya, fun to test for sure, though a flash drive would be easy to test with.

Comment: A similar question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227835/how-i-could-to-run-formatting-disk-programmatically/9166558#9166558

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425%28VS.85%29.aspx) to launch a hidden copy of the cmd.exe format command, and feed it characters to handle the prompting.  This is in Pascal, but it's all API calls, so it should translate pretty easily.  You'll need to add some error handling too, and make sure you test it extensively.

Win32_Volume::Format was only added in Windows 2003, so it won't work if you need WinXP or Win2K support.

```
procedure FormatFloppy;
var
  sa: TSecurityAttributes;
  si: TStartupInfo;
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  BytesWritten: LongWord;
  hInRead, hInWrite: THandle;
begin
  // Initialize security information
  sa.nLength := SizeOf(sa);
  sa.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  sa.bInheritHandle := True;
  CreatePipe(hInRead, hInWrite, @sa, 0);
  // Initialize startup info
  ZeroMemory(@si, SizeOf(si));
  si.cb := SizeOf(si);
  si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  si.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  si.hStdInput := hInRead;
  si.hStdOutput := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  si.hStdError := GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
  // Start process
  ZeroMemory(@pi, SizeOf(pi));
  CreateProcess(nil, 'cmd /c format a: /fs:FAT /F:1.44 /V:', nil, nil, True,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, si, pi);
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
  CloseHandle(hInRead);
  // Write '<enter>' to start processing, and 'n<enter>' to respond to question at end
  WriteFile(hInWrite, #13#10'N'#13#10, 5, BytesWritten, nil);
  CloseHandle(hInWrite);
  // Wait for process to exit
  WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
end;
```

Comment: I have no disk to try this on, but I think it is the best way of doing it. +1

Comment: Spawning a console+format.com is one way of doing it, but is certainly not "all API calls".

Comment: @GravityWell That comment was in regards to it being Pascal code that only used Win32 API functions without calls into the Pascal RTL, which would allow it to be ported to C++ easily.  It had nothing to do with the implementation details, which, while admittedly janky, are/were what was available.

Comment: *"Here's how you launch a process in Delphi"* is not an answer to the question *"How do I format a disk in C++?"* You might think this would accomplish the same until you consider error reporting. There isn't any here and the procedure should really be called `MaybeFormatSomeDrive`.

Answer (score 7):

You might use the [SHFormatDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762169(VS.85).aspx) function to display the Format Drive dialog box in Windows.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way of doing it is to use Virtual Disk Service [FormatPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381685%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

Comment: -1: This is not a complete answer, should probably be a comment, and isn't necessarily true. Formatting a drive and formatting a partition are simply different tasks. Also, note that this question is 3.5 years old.

Comment: The problem with this approach is it doesn't works before Vista

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not offer such low level API.

What OS/platform are you using ?

On Windows, There is a WMI API that does that : [Win32_Volume Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390432%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Or you could try using "system" (or on Windows, "ShellExecute" ?);

Good luck.

Max.

Comment: I know that api what i cannot use it.I mean I could not find any sample code for use of that

Answer (score 0):

You can call `system("format  C: /FS:NTFS /X /Q /y");`  where "C:" is disk to format.