# C++ Auto Format

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that auto formats my f:\ (USB Drive), and I have this code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  system ("format f:");
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Now, when I run that, it comes up, with me needing to press <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>. How can I simulate that?

Comment: Why are you doing this in C++? Just write a batch script; it will be much less painful.

Comment: This program sounds... dangerous.

Comment: @James It's not really any more dangerous than a batch script that does the same thing, it's just a bit more roundabout

Comment: @Michael:  That's true, but I wouldn't want a batch script or any other program like that lying around on my machine :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format drive by c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648305/format-drive-by-c)

Answer (score 1):

As Tyler said in a comment, a batch file would be much easier, but this might work:

```
system( "echo y | format f:" )
```