# Is there any way to set the disk signature programmatically, rather than disk part

Tags: c++, windows, disk

Creating an application where multiple disks with duplicate disk signatures will be present in the machine- to solve that one, I am making the duplicate disks as online, so that disk signature will change and will do some work.

At the end I want a way set the disk signature of that duplicated disk to original disk signature after making the disk as offline.

Disk part is working with below commands
opened command prompt as a administrator, performed the below commands

```
> diskpart 

> select disk 

> uniqueid disk id = xxxxxxxx
```

Disk signature changed successfully.

I need a solution to change the disk signature programmatically.
I do not want a solution like calling the diskpart commands in program.

Comment: _"I do not want a solution like calling the diskpart commands in program."_ Can I ask why not?

Comment: Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/3879294/560648

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit,
Thank yor for reply.
There is no particular reason to not to use diskpart commands, seeking for suggestion like any other approach better than this is exists or not.