# How I could to run formatting disk programmatically?

Tags: c++, filesystems, format

I search variants **to format** hard or usb disks programmatically. I founded api-function `SHFormatDrive`, but here use windows-dialog. To my mind, this method not bad, but how i could to hide/forbid this dialog. Anywhere, i continue search a way to format disks programmatically.

Comment: @Adrien: True, had a weak moment. Removing my comment.

Comment: The linked answer is tagged winapi, while this one is more general. I vote to re-open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Format method of the Win32_Volume class. [Details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390432%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Could you give example of implementation this class (methods etc.)?

Comment: I don't have a code sample handy, but if you haven't use WMI in c++ before, this might help get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your references, but I'm think that it is so hard way.

Comment: You can call system("format  C: /FS:NTFS /X /Q /y"); where "C:" is disk to format.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing it is to use Virtual Disk Service [FormatPartition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381685%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows systems, you can do a "silent" format by using ::CreateProcess() to execute a DOS format command.

See these 2 links for details.
CreateProcess() API: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/9505Yamaha_1.aspx
DOS format command: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070712051040AAIny5w

Good luck!

Comment: -1 Very bad since this is no single API call but a very heavy weighted error prone hack. Should be avoided!