# How to send symbol or 'Enter' to cmd.exe started by CreateProcess

Tags: winapi, pascal

I need to write a symbol to the console window or send <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. I am using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2654500/6016432)
with some changes:

```
procedure Console_Std_Input_Test;
var
  sa: TSecurityAttributes;
  si: TStartupInfo;
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  BytesWritten: LongWord;
  hInRead, hInWrite: THandle;
begin
  // Initialize security information
  sa.nLength := SizeOf(sa);
  sa.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  sa.bInheritHandle := True;
  CreatePipe(hInRead, hInWrite, @sa, 0);
  // Initialize startup info
  ZeroMemory(@si, SizeOf(si));
  si.cb := SizeOf(si);
  si.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  si.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  si.hStdInput := hInRead;
  si.hStdOutput := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  si.hStdError := GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
  // Start process
  ZeroMemory(@pi, SizeOf(pi));
  CreateProcess(nil, 'cmd /k ', nil, nil, True,
    CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, nil, nil, si, pi);
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
  CloseHandle(hInRead);
  // Write '<enter>' 
  WriteFile(hInWrite, #13#10, 2, BytesWritten, nil);// nothing happens!!
  //WriteFile(hInWrite, #48#49#50, 3, BytesWritten, nil);//write "012"-nothing appears too!
  CloseHandle(hInWrite);
  // Wait for process to exit
  WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
end;
```

I've spent all day trying to solve this problem, but I can't understand how to send <kbd>Enter</kbd> or some symbols to console. I've looked at samples on MSDN and Microsoft Support, but didn't find anything different from the code above, and really can't understand where my mistake is.

Comment: I would try with a simpler command like `pause` to see if it works.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre, yes, I made CreateProcess(nil, 'cmd /k pause'...), and still nothing happens. Console is waiting for the input key

Comment: I mean just `pause`. Well, I guess it will do the same. Try adding several #13#10 sequences too.

Comment: Can't understand, what do you mean..

Comment: Don't spam tags! This is neither C nor C++!

Comment: Quite possibly the most justified Olaf slap-down in history.

Comment: do you really need this to be pascal?

Comment: No,i need winapi. C,C++,Pascal - doesn't matter. All I want to know is how to send symbol or 'Enter' to cmd started with CreateProcess.

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using? `#13#10` and `#48#49#50` do not produce the same **byte sequences** in Delphi 2007 and earlier as they do in Delphi 2009 and later. Your code is assuming pre-D2009 behavior. Also, did you read this article on MSDN? [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx). You are not doing everything it does to setup the pipes. In particular, you are not removing `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` from `hInWrite` before calling `CreateProcess()`.

Comment: @Remu Lebeau,thanks a lot! That was my mistake. When i paste "SetHandleInformation" it started work well. I'm using Ada+C, and I've copied that code just for example to understand how to use pipe with cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

@Remu Lebeau answered the question in the comments:

> In particular, you are not removing HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT from hInWrite before calling CreateProcess()

That was my mistake.